# How to make this simple 301 redirect in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've looked to some already asked questions, but wasn't able to solve it.

How do I make a simple 301 redirect

FROM:
www.mydomain.cz/something/somethingelse/

TO 
www.mydomain.cz/sometext

I've came up with this, but it didn't work and I don't really know the difference between RedirectMatch and RewriteRule, could anyone tell? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 something/somethingelse(/)?$ sometext
```

I get an "Internal Server Error" when using this.

Answer (score 0):

nice easy one..

Redirect 301 /oldfolder/oldfile.html http://www.domain.com/Content/newfile.html

http://www.techieshelp.com/how-to-redirect-a-web-page/

Comment: Well, I then use some more rewriting, that messes with this one, is there a way to tell the .htaccess to stop reading the .htaccess, if this redirect is matched?